# Angular - Issues linking controller and service

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and working from the [angularjs-template](https://github.com/pamigomp/angularjs-template) seed projet. I am having problems linking my controller and service. The code runs fine but I don't seem to get any data returned back into the controller.

I have googled quiet a bit and read simimar posts on this forum but after trying various differnt approaches I still can't get this to work.

**listController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.node.list', ['app.nodeService'])
            .controller('NodeListController', NodeListController);

    NodeListController.$inject = ['$log', 'nodeService'];

    function NodeListController($log, nodeService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.node = [];

        //vm.node = [{name: 'michael'}, {name: 'carol'}]

        retrieve();

        //  ***************************************************************************
            $log.info('About to print contents of vm.node');
            $log.info(vm.node);
        // ***************************************************************************

        function retrieve() {
            return getJson().then(function () {
                $log.info('Retrieved Json');
            });
        }

        function getJson() {
            return nodeService.getAPIData().then(function (data) {
                vm.node = data;
                //  ***************************************************************************
                    $log.info('About to print contents of data and vm.node in getJSON');
                    $log.info(data);
                     $log.info(vm.node);
                // ***************************************************************************
                return vm.node;
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

**nodeService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.nodeService', [])
        .factory('nodeService', nodeService);

    nodeService.$inject = ['$http', '$log', '$q'];

    function nodeService($http, $log, $q) {

        return {
            getAPIData: getAPIData
        };

        function getAPIData(){
            //  ***************************************************************************
            $log.info('getAPIData Started');
            //  ***************************************************************************
            return $http.get("https://n4nite-api-n4nite.c9users.io/v1/imm/summary")
                .then(getAPIDataComplete)
                .catch(getAPIDataFailed)

            function getAPIDataComplete(response){
                //  ***************************************************************************
                    $log.info('getAPIDataComplete Started');
                    $log.info('Printing contents of getAPIDataComplete response.data');
                    $log.info(response.data);
                // ***************************************************************************
                return response.data;
            }

            function getAPIDataFailed(error){
                $log.info('getAPIFailed Started');
                var newMessage = 'XHR Failed for getData.';
                $log.error(newMessage);
                return $q.reject(error);
            }
        }

    }
})();
```

**Console:**
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Can you add some logs in `getAPIDataComplete` and `getJson` methods just to see is data returned from the service? It seems that your endpoint is working, but I'm not sure why your `vm.node` variable is empty. Also, you don't need `return vm.node;`.

Comment: What is printed in the console? What happens when you use your debugger? What do you get as a response in the network tab of your browser dev tools?

Comment: Im away from my pc right now but I will post the logs in a couple of hours. Thanka

Comment: I have added logs and my console to the original question above now.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, you have successfully linked your service with your controller and I see that your service is reterning results in the console log right after the message "Printing contents of getAPIDataComplete response.data". What is the problem ?

Comment: I am not getting anything back in the html. I just found that if I remove the code "vm.node = [];" from my controller then I get the results on screen as I expect.